# Inner product on space of functions from $R^n \rightarrow R^m$?

Tags: functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Is the space of functions from $R^n$ to $R^m$ a [Hilbert space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space)?  It seems pretty obvious that it's a vector space, but I'm not sure how to extend the inner product on functions $R^n \rightarrow R$ to functions in $m$D.  Does this space of functions (possibly with some restrictions such a smoothness) admit an inner product?  If so, what is that product?  If there are more than one, is there a "natural" one that is related to the single-dimensional function case?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525873/orthonormal-bases-for-the-space-of-functions-from-cn-rightarrow-cm

Answer (score 2):

Let $\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}) = \left(f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n),\dots, f_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right)^T$ and $\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{x})$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. In my opinion, the following definition of inner product is quite straightforward:
$$
\left<\boldsymbol{f}, \boldsymbol{g}\right> = \sum_{i=1}^m \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_i(\boldsymbol{x}) g_i(\boldsymbol{x}) \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{x} = 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^m f_i(\boldsymbol{x}) g_i(\boldsymbol{x}) \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{x}.
$$
You can check as an exercise that all needed properties are satisfied. Of course, you need some assuptions on $\boldsymbol{f}$ and $\boldsymbol{g}$ hold, i.e. integrability and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{i=1}^m f_i^2(\boldsymbol{x}) \mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{x} < \infty$ (and same for $\boldsymbol{g}$).

Comment: @Yaddle Though, if you look at the question, the asker is prepared to add extra restrictions on the space: "Does this space of functions **(possibly with some restrictions such a smoothness)** admit an inner product?". The answer also states the restrictions at the bottom, so I think this is a reasonable answer to the question. (+1)

Comment: @Yaddle I’ve mentioned precisely that $f, g$ need to be square-integrable.